# To Connect to Cassandra Server takes long time

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am using a driver which is in following link for c#

https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver

It seems really good. But problem is time issue. I am waiting to connect or execute somequery longer than 1 minute. I tried [cassandraemon](http://cassandraemon.codeplex.com/),it connected in 1-2 seconds. But It dont like this library much and want to use another one.

So here is my connection code.. where is my mistake?

```
        try
        {
            cluster = Cluster.Builder()
                           // .AddContactPoints(nodes)
                            .AddContactPoint("xx.xx.xx.xx")
                             .Build();
            session = cluster.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }          
        return true;
```

Comment: Code seems fine (assuming "xx.xx.xx.xx" is actually replaced by a real ip) so I'd start debugging the network.

Comment: @LyubenTodorov,thank you for you answer. If it was about network, why another driver connects fast? I installed cassandra on local, so with this driver,its quite fast. I think that it caused port number...